# Animating a scaling view from a corner (zooming in)

Tags: ios, core-animation

I'm trying to scale my view like so:

```
CGRect endFrame = self.detailView.bounds;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    self.descriptionButton.bounds = endFrame;
}completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    self.containerView.alpha = 0.0;
    self.detailView.alpha = 1.0;
}];
```

My detailView is the container view.  My descriptionButton is in the upper left corner.  I want to give a zoom in type effect by having the button take up the whole screen.  However, by default Core Animation scales from the anchor point at its center.

I tried setting the anchor point to the lower right corner of the view's layer like this:

```
self.descriptionButton.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(self.descriptionButton.bounds.size.width, self.descriptionButton.bounds.size.height);

CGRect endFrame = self.detailView.bounds;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    self.descriptionButton.bounds = endFrame;
}completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    self.containerView.alpha = 0.0;
    self.detailView.alpha = 1.0;
}];
```

But when I do that, I don't see any animation at all.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a little math

```
CGRect endFrame = self.detailView.frame;
CGRect currentFrame = self.detailView.frame;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^
 {
     self.descriptionButton.frame = CGRectMake(currentFrame.x - (endFrame.size.width - currentFrame.size.width), currentFrame.y - (endFrame.size.height - currentFrame.size.height), endFrame.size.width, endFrame.size.height);
 }
                                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {
     self.containerView.alpha = 0.0;
     self.detailView.alpha = 1.0;
 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

The anchorPoint property is "normalized" to values from 0 to 1. 0.5, 0.5 is the center. 0,0 is top left. 1,1 is bottom right.

Your code is setting the anchorPoint property using pixel coordinates, which is wrong. I don't know what it would do, but it's wrong.